# AsyncTask gets out of step when hitting Home button over and over again

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask, runtimeexception

I have an AsyncTask which does a lot of JSON calculations.

```
public class InitializationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, InitializationResult> {
    private ProcessController processController = new ProcessController();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public InitializationTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Die Daten werden aufbereitet.\nBitte warten...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true); //means that the "loading amount" is not measured.
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    };

    @Override
    protected InitializationResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return processController.initializeData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InitializationResult result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (result.isValid())  {
            mainActivity.finalizeSetup();
        }
        else  {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
            dialog.setTitle("Initialisierungsfehler");
            dialog.setMessage(result.getReason());
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();

                            mainActivity.finish();
                        }
                    });

            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

processController.initializeData() runs for about 20 seconds. All this works. It even works when I install the application, and pressing home button while application is initializing. The AsyncTask is working in the background. When I restart the application from Android device again **after the AsyncTask has been finished**, the application still works.
But the application cannot handle this use case: When I deploy the application (or start it when no data is initialized), so that it really takes about 20sec to initialize the data and when I hit home to close the application while initialization (the AsyncTask) runs in the background and start the application again, it leads to unexpected behavior as RuntimExceptions and so on. It seems that the device wants to load the application twice, but none of them can start successfully. How to deal with that?
I thought about checking if there is a running AsyncTask in MainActivity to avoid starting it again:

```
private InitializationTask initializationTask = new InitializationTask(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (!AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING.equals(initializationTask.getStatus()))  {
        initializationTask.execute((Void[])null);
    }

    initializeMap();
}
```

Unfortunately this does do nothing. Moreover I'm not sure if such use case is possible at all, because when I start the same application twice, they cannot "share" an AsyncTask. Should I somehow avoid starting the application twice or something? I'm not sure what options do I have on this? Any ideas?

Comment: also make sure you're not leaving the task running after onPause.

Comment: @Tom Dignan Ok, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: It's actually not an AsyncTask issue. The problem was that my parse method of JSONParser (that does the most of the work) which is invoked in processController.initializeData(), was not synchronized.

Comment: does processController.initializeData() run on a separate thread? You don't need to do that, because doInBackground is already invoked for you in a thread pool. onPreExecute, doInBackground, and onPostExecute will always execute one after the other, doInBackground on a separate thread, and the other two on the main/UI thread.

Comment: @Tom Dignan No, processController.initializeData() is not a separate thread. The problem is that JSONSimple.parse is not synchronized, that's why I have to synchronize my parse method, which uses this method. The main problem is that the parsing takes about 20sec and when I start a new AsyncTask, and the previous parsing has not been finish yet, an unsynchronized parse method could not handle this. When I synchronize it, it's not getting settled anymore. (And I also use the code of your link, maybe the combination of both was the right solution)

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it a bit more bluntly. I set my `AsyncTask` reference to null when I'm not using it. When the `onClick` fires, I check if it's not null, which means I started it. If it is null, I create and execute a new `AsyncTask` right there. It is plenty fast and it's clean enough. One bonus of this approach is that an `AsyncTask` *can only be executed once anyway*, so it fits in well with that. At the end of `onPostExecute`, you can set the reference back to `null` again if you intend to stay in the same `Activity`.

While you're perfecting your AsyncTask flow, make sure that it [survives orientation changes](http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/rotating-async-tasks) as well.

Comment: Do you mean onCreate instead of onClick?

Comment: I think my problem is different. The methods which are invoked by the task get out of step due to NullPointerExceptions or Exception caused by the JSON framework. It seems that these methods are still executed somehow but with corrupt data due to Task cancellation.

Comment: ...by the way: getLastNonConfigurationInstance() which is used in this code example of your link is deprecated.

Comment: @Bevor -- Sure, I'm completely aware of that. That doesn't change the fact that there's code in the wild that still uses such an approach. Regardless, you will need to take care of orientation changes. -- If you are declaring an AsyncTask inside of an Activity and not a Fragment then your best shot at persisting it on an orientation change is to use the method articulated in the above approach. You can point out that the method is deprecated, but right now you are writing your code in a way the depends on deprecated methods to work properly (or use a service, which is a different conversation)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "writing your code in a way the depends on deprecated methods". What exactly is deprecated on my code?

Comment: @Bevor since you are not using a fragment the only supported way to retain the async task on an orientation change is with the deprecated method you're harping about -- either use a fragment or use the deprecated method, or use a service, which is not really the right choice.